# What do you get for mining the new Christmas tree?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Has anyone mined one yet?

I really don't want to mine but I'm curious what you get if you do.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gives you 75,000 gold. So you get back 50,000 in return for cutting it that costs 25,000. No difference to other X-mas trees. Just a new design. I recommend to preserve these trees, as these trees *might* give you presents daily.

---

Added information:

As of 12/29/15, there is still no present/gift spawning beside the trees.

Comment: Ah... How often do these trees respawn??

Comment: do you know what the presents give you?

Comment: So same as with Cauldron eccept gold?

Comment: Trees appear randomly through time, but a bigger yard space (or how do you call the space left in your base, where troops can deploy) helps these trees to grow randomly just like how every obstacle (i.e., bush, etc.) grow on it. As far as I know, presents give as much as 5k elixir. It's pretty much small when you're on high levels, so it's better off a decoration/souvenir. And yes, it's the same effect with cauldrons, but elixir.

Comment: This year's Christmas trees *do not* appear to spawn presents. That was  last year's (2014) trees, which, by the way, are not spawning any more presents. So by all means, cut down all of the trees if you need gold.

Comment: Yes, that was what I observed as well. Maybe they're better off as quick golds. But I still feel something special about it, I ain't cutting it 'til the team calls off spawning more of them.